# JFrame.getComponentCount with 3 jPanels returns 1

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating MTG game for school Java class and I run into problem. I'm currenty testing something... I have my game GUI (extends from `JFrame`), and when I doublclick on exile "pile" I create a new `JFrame`, then I add my cards into this `JFrame` (`Card` extends `JPanel`) and I tried to `setsize` based on `frame.getComponentCount()`

But problem is, it returns 1, whether a card was added or not.. like my card wasn't even counted as a component.

Code:

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame();          
       Image cardImage;
       cardImage = ImageIO.read(new File("pics/background.png")).getScaledInstance(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
       frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));             
       frame.add(new Card(cardImage,false));
       frame.add(new Card(cardImage,false));
       frame.add(new Card(cardImage,false));            
       frame.setSize(frame.getComponentCount()*80, frame.getComponentCount()*80);                   
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
       frame.setVisible(true);
```

So my `frame.setSize` doesn't work, because of wrong return.
...
Can anyone help me identify a problem? I don't get it, because `frame.add` input parameter is component (according to javadoc), but when I try `getComponentCount` is isn't counted as a component.

Just to be clear, everything else work, I get the new window, there are 3 cards as they supposed to be, I just have to manually resize it to see them.

Comment: What is the frame size that your are getting right now?

Comment: well, getComponentCount is returning 1, so I'm getting (1*80,1*80)

Comment: did you debug the code to see if `frame.getComponentCount()` returns 1 or not?

Comment: I've tryed System.out.println(frame.getComponentCount()); between every add, and it returned 1 every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting back the count from the JFrame's single contentPane component. To get the sub components, call the method on the contentPane itself.

```
frame.getContentPane().getComponentCount()
```

But regardless, your design for setting size this way seems brittle, and is not how I would do things. Instead, have your components return their own best preferred sizes and call `pack()` on your JFrame after adding components.

Comment: Thanks! this works Now I'm going to read something about ContentPane :D

Comment: Well, thank you again, `frame.pack()` does work too. I'm very new in swing, we didn't even talk about it in our lessons, so I'm working ahead... but obviously, I dont know some basic methods yet.